# How to animate progress inside button?

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I have a voice button in my View Controller . The image to which is attached below.
[image]

I want to animate this image with circular progress indicator when I am doing some function . How can i achieve this animation?

Note: I don't want to attach gif images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set imageview behind button.

Than put this code on button action.

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.gif"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

you can load gif images background on button using this trick.